# Augment default export in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Some packages export only a single object. If I were to overwrite/extend that object: How would I do that?

After searching a lot of answers this is where I am:

```js
import axios from "axios";

declare module "axios" {
  const axios: {
    not: () => void;
  };

  export = axios; // <- Exports and export assignments are not permitted in module augmentations.
}

axios.not();
```

*This question is not about whether it is practical to overwrite axios  here*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript has declaration merging abilities, unfortunately, in your case you won't be able to leverage it because of its [limitations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#disallowed-merges):

> Disallowed Merges
> Not all merges are allowed in TypeScript. Currently, classes can not merge with other classes or with variables. For information on mimicking class merging, see the Mixins in TypeScript section.

As the documentation says, on the other hand you can leverage [mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html) to create your own class that extends `Axios`:

```
import { Axios } from "axios";

type AxiosConstructor = new (...args: any[]) => Axios;

function augmentAxios<T extends AxiosConstructor>(axios: T) {
    return class AugmentedAxios extends axios {
        newAbility() {}
    };
}

const AugmentedAxios = augmentAxios(Axios);

const augmentedAxios = new AugmentedAxios({});

augmentedAxios.post('http://test'); // Base ability
augmentedAxios.newAbility(); // New ability
```